# boto HTMLQuestion create-hit -- should see HIT in Requester sandbox?

Tags: boto, mechanicalturk

I've submitted a HTMLQuestion using the boto/create-hit API. It returned a valid response and I see it if I use boto to list my HITs. However, I don't see the HIT in the Manage Batches page of the requester sandbox.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that API-created HITs don't show up in the Manage Batches pane, only in the Manage HITs Individually link.

Answer (score 0):

API generated HITs can still be found here: https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/manageHITs

Comment: Pleas at least rewrite the most important things, not just paste the link.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the most important things? He tries to access the HITs he created using the API via boto and they don't show up in the HITs manager, but there is a way to access them using the link I posted above. Actually you just have to add "/manageHITs" to your mturk manager path. Please let me know, if you need further explanations, Niemand.